# How to merge 2 rows in a html table

Tags: html, merge, row, html-table

I would like to merge 2 rows in table , i already merged 2 rows but i cant figure it out how to merge the first row and the second row of the table..

I would like to merge my rows in this scheme

```
|---------------------------|
|            row1           |
|---|                   |---|
cell|        row2       | cell
|---|                   |---|
|            row3           |
|---------------------------|
```

but i can only merge them like this

```
|---------------------------|
|            row1           |
|---|-------------------|---|
cell|        row2       | cell
|---|                   |---|
|            row3           |
|---------------------------|
```

if i try to use rowspan again i don't get the result i want!
My entire code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border=1px>


<tr class="tr_top" >
    <td colspan = "3"  >1</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr_middle" >
    <td width=7% style="background-color:transparent;">c</td>
    <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td width=7% style="background-color:transparent;">c</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr_down">
    <td colspan = "3" >3</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea?
Than you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you trying to merge the 1st row to your already merged 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: Yes pretty much this is what im trying ...

Comment: Well I'm kinda working on an answer for you, but in the meantime you may want to check [this](http://www.angelfire.com/fl5/html-tutorial/tables/rowspan.htm) out.  Its what I'm working from.  Although judging from that and what I've tried so far, I'm not sure you can achieve your exact formatting

Comment: Thank you very much ,i am also working on the materials you gave me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with html and some css

html

```
<body>
<table>
<tr class="tr_top" >
    <td colspan = "3">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tdBorder" width=7%> c</td>
    <td >2</td>
    <td class="tdBorder" width=7%>c</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_down">
    <td colspan = "3" >3</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

css

```
table{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tr_top{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.tr_down{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.tdBorder{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td{
    text-align: center;
}
```

check this here https://jsfiddle.net/1fbe87r5/

Answer (score 4):

I assume rowspan works identical to colspan. Please note that if this is true the "merged" `<td>` become ONE `<td>`just as they do with colspan. Rowspan and colspan do not "merge" subsequent tds, they just tell the current  on which they are applied to consume the space of the number of cols/rows specified.

Check this example to understand how rowspan works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Combining cells in a table rowise - rowspan</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Kindergarten consists of</td>
      <td>Kinder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>+ Garten</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Blitzkrieg consists of</td>
      <td>Blitz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>+ Krieg</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

use the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border=1px>


<tr class="tr_top" >
    <td colspan = "3"  >1</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr_middle" >
    <td width=7% style="background-color:transparent;">c</td>
    <td >2</td>
    <td width=7% style="background-color:transparent;">c</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr_down">
    <td colspan = "3" >3</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but this example doesn't merge my rows :/